# Asp.net MVC - Culture is not supported. Parameter name: name 1 is an invalid culture identifier

Tags: .net, asp.net-mvc

I am getting this error

> Culture is not supported.
>   Parameter name: name
>   1 is an invalid culture identifier

I am using following server configuration,

```
CultureInfo: “ja” 
Windows Server 2016 Datacenter
SQL server 2017
.Net v4.7.2
```

LINQ is working correctly but when I am trying to execute raw SQL using EF it's throwing CultureNotFoundException.

Also, on the local machine with local db, it's working correctly but when I connect DB server it's throwing an exception

Changing SQL server collation solved this problem but is there any other way to solve this?

[image: Function]

Comment: Share some code where you get this error.

Comment: Please check function in the image. On the last line database.SqlQuery statement I am getting that error.